# TypeScript stepUp method throws an error on an input type number

Tags: typescript

I have a problem trying to use the method `stepUp` on an input type number https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

Here is the code i'm trying to run:

```js
var box = document.getElementById("box");
var inputNode = box.querySelectorAll(".increment-input");

inputNode[0].stepUp(6);
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <input type="number" step="1" value="1" class="increment-input">
</div>
```

Typescript throws:

**Property 'stepUp' does not exist on type 'Element'.**

http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20box%20%3D%20document.getElementById(%22box%22)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20var%20inputNode%20%3D%20box.querySelectorAll(%22.increment-input%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20inputNode%5B0%5D.stepUp()%3B

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that TypeScript, in order to provide type safety, says that your list `inputNode` is a `NodeListOf<Element>` as `querySelectorAll()`could return a list of whatever HTML-Element there could occur. So if you are pretty sure about the actual type of the current `Element` you have to cast it to that type. Then you'll be enabled to use its specific functions.

```
public collectAndStepUp(): void {
    const box = document.getElementById("box");
    const inputNode = box.querySelectorAll(".increment-input");

    // type cast from Element to HTMLInputElement
    const htmlInputElement = inputNode[0] as HTMLInputElement;
    htmlInputElement.stepUp(5);
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: Here you go. It'd be nice if you could mark this answer as solution if it is the solution to your problem. Thx in advance.

Comment: Thanks Lynx, I will test this when I get back to work Monday, but you will definitely get the nod because I think you have the solution to my problem. I won't forget you promise!

Comment: Thanks this is indeed the solution.